# Hardware wallet support of ERC-721 or Storing cryptokitties on Ledger Nano

Tags: erc-721, cryptokitties

I have a question related to hardware wallet support of ERC 721 tokens.
I plan to move a cryptokittie to a Ledger Nano wallet.

It's relatively easy to send it to an account controlled by Ledger. In the Cryptokitties UI I could select Send and type (or better paste) an address. The question is how to send it back from Ledger to an account controlled by Metamask, e.g. for breeding purposes.

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@igor-barinov,
From my understanding, you can connect Metamask to your ledger (via MM). Then send the cat to another address on the cryptokitties site.

Comment: Thanks, it was not available back in days but available now for both Trezor and Ledger via Metamask. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use the ledger support in mycrypto or myetherwallet to interact with the cryptokitties erc721 contract

Comment: is there any instruction on how to interact with the crypto kitties erc721 contract?